# Perl : Need to append two columns if the ID's are repeating

Tags: perl, append

If id gets repeated I am appending app1, app2 and printing it once.

***Input:***

```
id|Name|app1|app2    
1|abc|234|231|
2|xyz|123|215|
1|abc|265|321|
3|asd|213|235|
```

***Output:***

```
id|Name|app1|app2
1|abc|234,265|231,321|
2|xyz|123|215|
3|asd|213|235|
```

***Output I'm getting:***

```
id|Name|app1|app2
1|abc|234,231|
2|xyz|123,215|
1|abc|265,321|
3|asd|213,235|
```

***My Code:***

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $basedir = 'E:\Perl\Input\\';
my $file ='doctor.txt';
my $counter = 0;
my %RepeatNumber;
my $pos=0;
open(OUTFILE, '>', 'E:\Perl\Output\DoctorOpFile.csv') || die $!;
open(FH, '<', join('', $basedir, $file)) || die $!;
my $line = readline(FH);
unless ($counter) {
    chomp $line;
    print OUTFILE $line;
    print OUTFILE "\n";
}
while ($line = readline(FH)) {
    chomp $line;
    my @obj = split('\|',$line);
    if($RepeatNumber{$obj[0]}++) {
        my $str1= join("|",$obj[0]);
        my $str2=join(",",$obj[2],$obj[3]);
        print OUTFILE join("|",$str1,$str2);
        print OUTFILE "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_in = "doctor.txt";
open (FF, "<$file_in");

my $temp = <FF>; # remove first line

my %out; 

while (<FF>)
{
    my ($id, $Name, $app1, $app2) = split /\|/, $_;
    $out{$id}[0] = $Name;
    push @{$out{$id}[1]}, $app1;
    push @{$out{$id}[2]}, $app2;
}

foreach my $key (keys %out)
{
    print $key, "|", $out{$key}[0], "|", join (",", @{$out{$key}[1]}), "|",     join (",", @{$out{$key}[2]}), "\n";
}
```

***EDIT***

To see what the `%out` contains (in case it's not clear), you can use

```
use Data::Dumper;
```

and print it via

```
print Dumper(%out);
```

Comment: To explain in case it's not clear: `%out` is a hash with `Id` as the key and the value is a reference to an array. First item of this array is the `Name`; second item is a reference to an array of `App1` values and the second is a reference to an array of `App2` values.

Answer (score 1):

I'd tackle it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use 5.14.0;

my %stuff;

#extract the header row.
#use the regex to remove the linefeed, because
#we can't chomp it inline like this. 
#works since perl 5.14
#otherwise we could just chomp (@header) later. 
my ( $id, @header ) = split( /\|/, <DATA> =~ s/\n//r );

while (<DATA>) {

    #turn this row into a hash of key-values.
    my %row;
    ( $id, @row{@header} ) = split(/\|/);
    #print for diag 
    print Dumper \%row;

    #iterate each key, and insert into $row.
    foreach my $key ( keys %row ) {
        push( @{ $stuff{$id}{$key} }, $row{$key} );
    }
}

#print for diag    
print Dumper \%stuff;

print join ("|", "id", @header ),"\n";

#iterate ids in the hash
foreach my $id ( sort keys %stuff ) {

    #join this record by '|'.
    print join('|',
        $id,
        #turn inner arrays into comma separated via map.
        map {
            my %seen;
            #use grep to remove dupes - e.g. "abc,abc" -> "abc"
            join( ",", grep !$seen{$_}++, @$_ )
        } @{ $stuff{$id} }{@header}
        ),
        "\n";
}

__DATA__
id|Name|app1|app2
1|abc|234|231|
2|xyz|123|215|
1|abc|265|321|
3|asd|213|235|
```

This is perhaps a bit overkill for your application, but it should handle arbitrary column headings and arbitary numbers of duplicates. I'll coalesce them though - so the two `abc` entries don't end up `abc,abc`.

Output is:

```
id|Name|app1|app2
1|abc|234,265|231,321
2|xyz|123|215
3|asd|213|235
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it which doesn't use a hash (in case you want to be more memory efficient), my contribution lies under the opens:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $basedir = 'E:\Perl\Input\\';
my $file ='doctor.txt';
open(OUTFILE, '>', 'E:\Perl\Output\DoctorOpFile.csv') || die $!;
select(OUTFILE);
open(FH, '<', join('', $basedir, $file)) || die $!;

print(scalar(<FH>));
my @lastobj = (undef);
foreach my $obj (sort {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]}
                 map {chomp;[split('|')]} <FH>) {
    if(defined($lastobj[0]) &&
       $obj[0] eq $lastobj[0])
      {@lastobj = (@obj[0..1],
                   $lastobj[2].','.$obj[2],
                   $lastobj[3].','.$obj[3])}
    else
      {
        if($lastobj[0] ne '')
          {print(join('|',@lastobj),"|\n")}
        @lastobj = @obj[0..3];
      }
}
print(join('|',@lastobj),"|\n");
```

Note that split, without it's third argument ignores empty elements, which is why you have to add the last bar. If you don't do a chomp, you won't need to supply the bar or the trailing hard return, but you would have to record $obj[4].